# How does this array subtraction work without assignment?

Tags: arrays, c

The array does not have any assigned values, but when subtracting the values in the array, the **z** value becomes 20. 
Can anyone explain this concept? 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10][20][30][40];
    int z = a[6] - a[5];

    printf("%d\n", z); // z value is 20. why?
}
```

Comment: why shouldn't it be 20? the array can have any old random numbers in it because you didn't say you wanted specific numbers

Comment: But you are not subtracting values.

Comment: The array is uninitialized and could be filled with anything. It just so happens that `a[6] - a[5] = 20`, but that is absolutely no guarantee.

Comment: @user253751 I beg to differ. It has 20 because of the way jagged arrays are implemented. The first dim of `a` will hold pointers to the second dim, which holds pointers to the third dim, which hold pointers to the fourth dim which contain the actual data.

Comment: It's pointer subtraction, not value subtraction.

Comment: I used the local vsCode C compiler and obtained a value of 20 for 'z'. I also tried an online C compiler, which also returned 20.

Comment: @norok2 that's not how multidimentional arrays in C work.

Comment: @norok2.  The example code does not demonstrate "jagged" arrays.  There are no pointers stored within.

Comment: This code behavior is perfectly well defined. `a[6]` and `a[5]` are *arrays* by themselves, so subtracting them is subject of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @norok2 there is no jagged array in this code. Those are true native arrays of arrays (of arrays of arrays, in fact). This is basic, but no-so-subtle, pointer arithmetic.

Comment: sorry I meant [Iliffe vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector), I just use them only for jagged arrays but you are right that they are not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is it well defined though? is it guaranteed that `&a[6][0] == &a[5][20]`?

Comment: @YakovGalka Well, I guess it boils down to if it is guaranteed that `sizeof( type a[5*20] ) == sizeof (type a[5][20])`. You made me doubt though

Comment: @YakovGalka Yes, `&a[6][0] == &a[5][20]` always true with `int a[10][20][30][40];`.

Comment: @Creek Try changing `int a[10][20][30][40];` to `int a[10][7][30][40];`.  Is the output now 7?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what in the standard implies that though? that `sizeof(T[n]) == sizeof(T)*n`?

Comment: @YakovGalka It is somewhat involved.  Post as a SO question if you like - yet their might be a duplicate.

Comment: @YakovGalka Note that `intptr_t` is a common yet optional type.  So [`(intptr_t)(p+i) - (intptr_t)p == sizeof(*p)*i`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474037/how-does-this-array-subtraction-work-without-assignment?noredirect=1#comment133165181_75474112) **not** completely guaranteed.  Further, math like `-` only makes sense if one assumes that converting a pointer to an `intptr_t` results in a linear memory model.  That is certainly not guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> z value is 20. why?

Given `int a[10][20][30][40];`, `a[6]` indicates an array, an array of 20 elements.

When used in subtraction like `a[6] - a[5]`, the arrays are converted to the address of the type of their first elements.  So it is like `&a[6][0] - &a[5][0]`.  `&a[6][0]` is a *pointer*.  The pointer type they share is not so important here.

Pointer subtraction returns the difference in *elements* as an integer of type `ptrdiff_t`.  There are 20 elements between `&a[6][0]` and `&a[5][0]`.

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` ... C17dr § 6.5.6 9

Code then assigns a 20 (of type `ptrdiff_t`) to `z`, an `int`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is technically undefined behavior. At least in C++, probably in C as well.

In practice it will almost certainly print 20, as explained by other answers, but it violates `C11 6.5.6 Additive operators / 9` (and in C++: [`[expr.add]/4.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4.2)):

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
> or one past the last element of the array object ...

Your pointers point to two *different* arrays: to the first elements of `a[6]` and `a[5]` respectively.

One could argue that the first element of `a[6]` is one past the last element of `a[5]`, but at least in C++, it's not the case, even though they have the same value: notoriously, how a pointer was derived does matter (that's why things like [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) exist).

A non-UB way of computing the same thing would be:

```
int z = ((uintptr_t)a[6] - (uintptr_t)a[5]) / sizeof(a[0][0]);
```

This is technically implementation-defined (because of pointer-to-`uintptr_t` conversion), but should have an even smaller chance of breaking.

Comment: Your point about "pointers point to two different arrays:" is interesting though - they are different arrays _within_ a larger common array, hmmm.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Mhm, but for the common array to matter, `-` would need to have custom wording for multidimensional arrays, and there's none.

Comment: Good fix, not yet in agreement with _even smaller chance of breaking_.  "would need to have custom wording for multidimensional arrays" --> other possibilities exist. I suspect deep in the bowels of the C spec, the fact that array `a[6]` and `a[5]` are themselves part of the larger common array makes `a[6] - a[5]` well defined.  Just getting too deep for me today.

Comment: Would `int z = ((char *)a[6] - (char *)a[5]) / sizeof(a[0][0]);` be valid? `a[6]` and `a[5]` are different array objects but both are part of the same, larger object, so it might be OK. If it is valid, it avoids the implementation-defined nature of the pointer-to-`uintptr_t` conversion.

Comment: @IanAbbott It's moot. I think it's better than what OP does, and that's probably what I would do, but it could still be undefined. [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) has some interesting wording for "reachibility through a pointer", but I don't remember if it's clarified anywhere else in the standard. Shouldn't create any problems in the real world.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I removed the `sizeof(int) == 4` remark as it has no bearing on the result of pointer subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is pointer arithmetics.

`a[6]` is `20` elements of type `int[30][40]` from `a[5]`.

It happens because [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay)

Comment: I must admit that I'm a bit hazy about whether this subtraction is allowed. Even though it is obvious that `&a[6][0]` and `&a[5][20]` are the same value, does that make `&a[6][0] - &a[5][0]` just as legal as `&a[5][20] - &a[5][0]`?

Comment: @IanAbbott That subtraction is legal. `&a[5][20]` is illegal and any expression using it invokes UB

Comment: But does that also make `a[6] - a[4]` (i.e. `&a[6][0] - &a[4][0]`) legal? I think we are on shaky ground here.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm with you here that this is not at all obvious; but I think it follows from `sizeof(T[n]) == sizeof(T)*n` and `(intptr_t)(p+i) - (intptr_t)p == sizeof(*p)*i`, which I believe are guaranteed.

Comment: @IanAbbott no, it is ok

Comment: `&a[5][20]` is not illegal. It is the same pointer as `a[5] + 20` (or `&a[5][0] + 20`).

Comment: No , the second index is outside the range. It is UB even if it is inside the same array.

Comment: Are you saying that `&a[5][20]` is illegal but `a[5] + 20` and `&a[5][0] + 20` are OK?

Comment: @0___________, (@Ian Abbot) Why assert `&a[5][20]` is bad?  The 20 index is one-past the array end  - an allowable exception to array calculations.  Forming the address of an array is OK.   `printf("%p\n", (void *) &a[5][20]);`  is fine.

Comment: @YakovGalka I don't there are any such guarantees for `intptr_t`, but perhaps replacing `intptr_t` with `char *` is OK (i.e. `(char *)(p+i) - (char *)p == sizeof(*p)*i`) because any object can be treated as an array of `char` and the two `char` pointers are both pointing to bytes inside the object `a` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> The array does not have any assigned values, but when subtracting the values in the array, the z value becomes 20.

You are not subtracting any values in the array.  Not `int` values, anyway.

This declaration ...

> ```
> int a[10][20][30][40];
> ```

... says that `a` is an array of 10 (arrays of 20 (arrays of 30 (arrays of 40 `int`))).

Therefore `a[5]` and `a[6]` are each an array of 20 (arrays of 30 (arrays of 40 `int`)).

When array-valued expressions appear as operands in most kinds of expressions, they are automatically converted to pointers to their first elements, so `a[6] - a[5]` is equivalent to `&a[6][0] - &a[5][0]`.

Pointer differences are computed in units the size of the pointed-to type, so it doesn't actually matter for this purpose what the type of `a[5][0]` and `a[6][0]` is, or what `int` values are stored in the `a[i][j][k][l]`.  The value of the difference is fully determined by the second dimension of `a`, which is 20.